# Identify a Massachusetts Municipality from address

Tags: geocoding, address-parsing, fips

I am trying to create or utilize a lookup table to identify which Massachusetts Municipality my address is in. Do you know of an online resource available, or a way to identify the municiaplity uses FIPS codes? I currently only have the following fileds.

Address, City, State, Zip, MSA 5 digit, county 3 digit, state code 2 digit, census tract 6 digit.

Answer (score 1):

Massachusetts has [no unincorporated areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unincorporated_area#United_States), so the `City` name that you have should usually line up with the name of the municipality. Some addresses will use alternative names for informal neighborhoods or villages within legal municipalities; in this case, you can use this [*Archaic Community, District, Neighborhood Section and Village, Names in Massachusetts*](http://www.sec.state.ma.us/cis/cisuno/unoidx.htm) table to convert these to municipality name.